# Perl cpan installed modules are installed with an individual lib path

Tags: perl, cpan

Installing with the cpan cli tool modules - they are not found at script execution time basically as part of the @INC directories. I am using cygwin.

/home/myuser/.local/share/.cpan/build/Email-Sender-1.300031-0/lib/**Email/Sender/Simple.pm**
/home/myuser/.local/share/.cpan/build/Email-Simple-2.216-0/lib/**Email/Simple.pm**

I could now reference each single lib directory (they differ with each module installation) using the PERL5LIB Variable which is dull and boring. Am I doing something wrong? I want to install Perl Modules with cpan and use them afterwards without care where they are located...

Comment: .cpan/build is a temp directory for building and testing modules. Either test phase or install phase failed. You may need root privileges or use local::lib https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib to install modules.

Comment: Those aren't installation directories. Where did the modules actually get installed?

Comment: I use cpan -fi switches for some

Answer (score 0):

All the module installation failed because the 'make' utility was not installed.
Now the cpan modules get installed and can be used within my scripts.